# "partially initialized module (circular import)" with necessary import to use variable in both files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, object-oriented-analysis

In my imp_main.py I create two Charakters (char_01, char_03) from the Charakter class in imp_sub.py.

In imp_main.py I created a "current" variable to help to find the currently "picked" character object (e.g. char_01 or char_03).
I set current to "char_01" to pick char_01 as the current character.

I have a method in the Charakter class called "look" that looks for the "test" attribute in the currently picked object (in my case "char_01"). To use the correct object I use the eval function (eval(imp_main.current).test).

imp_sub.py:

```
import Testing.imp_main as imp_main


class Charakter:
    def __init__(self, test = False):
        self.test = test
    def look():
        if not eval(imp_main.current).test:
            print("Test False")
        else:
            print("Test True")
```

imp_main.py:

```
import Testing.imp_sub as imp_sub

current = "char_01"

char_01 = imp_sub.Charakter(True)
char_03 = imp_sub.Charakter(False)
imp_sub.Charakter.look()
```

I get the following error message: *AttributeError: partially initialized module 'Testing.imp_sub' has no attribute 'Charakter' (most likely due to a circular import)*

Writing this into one file works fine. The same goes for not importing the imp_main into imp_sub. But I wouldn't be able to use and edit the "current" variable without this import - that's why I have to "circular import", right?

I think I am probably doing a **fundamental** mistake using the class/import - but I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional wisdom is correct that global variables are bad and `eval` is, if anything, worse (use references to objects instead of strings that hold variable names).  But you can certainly use only one file here and assign to `current` by including `global current` at the beginning of the function that wants to write to it.